# In Tensorflow, how can I create a new tensor from a cosine similarity operation?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to create an output tensor with dimensionality `32 x 576 x 2` from an operation between matrices M and X, with the following shapes:

```
M.shape: (576, 2, 2048)
X.shape: (32, 2048)
```

The operation I'm defining is an element-wise cosine similarity, from the following equation:

[image]

which represents the cosine similarity between the feature vector  and the vector M_j,k.

This is how I've implemented it in code (incorrectly), where BATCH_SIZE=32, C=576, V=2:

```
    @tf.function
    def call(self, X):
        M = self.kernel

        norm_M = tf.norm(M, ord=2, axis=2)
        norm_X = tf.norm(X, ord=2, axis=1)

        l_r = (some scalar value, separate to this question)

        # Compute cosine similarity between X and M
        # as a matrix with dimensionality:
        # BATCH_SIZE x C x V
        feature_batch_size = tf.shape(X)[0]
        c = tf.shape(M)[0]
        v = tf.shape(M)[1]
        output_matrix = tf.zeros([feature_batch_size, c, v])
        output_matrix = tf.Variable(output_matrix, trainable=False)
        for row in tf.range(feature_batch_size):
          for column in tf.range(c):
            for channel in tf.range(v):
              a = tf.tensordot(M[column][channel], X[row], 1)
              b = norm_M[column][channel] * norm_X[row]
              output_matrix[row][column][channel] = a / b

        return [output_matrix, l_r]
```

This fails on the line `output_matrix[row][column][channel] = a / b` because it's unhappy with an assignment to an individual row:column:channel of a `tf.Variable`.

**Is there a better way to do this operation over these two matrices to create the desired output matrix** so that it can be done without these three nested for loops and maintain compatibility with the `tf.Function` graph functionality?

**If not, what can I do to assign variables to individual elements on a `tf.Variable`** as I'm unsuccessfully attempting to do here?

```
Extra information:
norm_M.shape: (576, 2)
norm_X.shape: (32,)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace these loops completely by using  `vectorized` operations in the place of `for loops`.

```
num = tf.einsum('ij,klj->ikl',X,M)
denom = tf.einsum('i,jk->ijk',norm_X, norm_M)
output_matrix = num/denom
```